# Cross domain issue for Express js and Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, cors

I have a node.js rest api built with Express framework version 4.11.1 and hosted in a server 'abc.com:5142'. Also have a front end website built with cg-angular which is hosted on the same domain but a different port 'abc.com:7070'.

When I access the front end causes a cross domain issue. I have tried almost all solutions including **cors** npm package. But it is not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this (keep the order):

```
var expr = require('express');
var app = expr.express();
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```